# Nutch Crawler error: Premission denied

Tags: java, hadoop, web-crawler, nutch

I am trying to run a basic crawler. Got the command from the NutchTutorial: bin/crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5

(after doing all the presets)

Im running from windows so I've installed cygwin64 as a running environment

I don't see any problems when I run bin/nutch from the nutch home directory, but when I try to run the crawl as above I get the following error:

```
Injector: starting at 2014-11-29 11:31:35
Injector: crawlDb: -dir/crawldb
Injector: urlDir: urls
Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
Injector: java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-Er
an\mapred\staging\Eran996102549\.staging to 0700
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkReturnValue(FileUtil.java:691)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.setPermission(FileUtil.java:664)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSys
tem.java:514)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.jav
a:349)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:19
3)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmi
ssionFiles.java:126)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:942)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInforma
tion.java:1190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:9
36)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:910)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1353)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.inject(Injector.java:324)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.run(Injector.java:380)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.main(Injector.java:370)
```

Theres no reference to that error on thier tutorial.
What do I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a permission problem. You should set Read,Write and Execute permission to the folder (`<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>` value in the Hadoop configuration file *core-site.xml*).

Hope this help,

Le Quoc Do