# Nutch Crawler Error: Hadoop Path Permissions

Tags: java, apache, mongodb, hadoop, web-crawler

I'm trying to run Apache Nutch (v2.3) with MongoDB (v2.6). I am following [this](http://www.aossama.com/search-engine-with-apache-nutch-mongodb-and-elasticsearch/) tutorial to help me get things set up. I have already created my seed list and my gora.properties and nutch-site.xml are set up fine. However, when running the `bin/nutch inject ../urls/test/` command, I keep getting a java.io.IOException error :

```
$ bin/nutch inject ./../../urls/test/
InjectorJob: starting at 2015-05-04 13:53:29
InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: ../../urls/test
InjectorJob: Using class org.apache.gora.mongodb.store.MongoStore as the Gora storage class.
InjectorJob: java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-TColletti\mapred\staging\TColletti1801159571\.staging to 0700
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkReturnValue(FileUtil.java:691)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.setPermission(FileUtil.java:664)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:514)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:349)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:126)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:942)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:550)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:580)
        at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:50)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:231)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:252)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:275)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:284)
```

I've read in some places this could be caused by not having the correct version of MongoDb or the Gora is wrong. It seems as though something is wrong with the permissions to a temp directory for hadoop(which im not using right now). I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27200873/nutch-crawler-error-premission-denied) S/O article but cannot find the *core-site.xml* file anywhere in my 2.3 version of Nutch.

Can someone help me finally run this command?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the official answer or not, but it worked for me. I found another S/O post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208736/failed-to-set-permissions-of-path-tmp/18381218#18381218). The general problem was the same. Other places kept mentioning about modifying core-site.xml which I did not have. However in one of the answers it mentions a patch to download and couple lines you need to add to the nutch-site.xml file in my runtime/local/conf directory. Tried it out and it solved my problems. It seems like the patch just ignored the errors and went around them. There may be a better solution to this but for now, it worked.